# Adding views and controllers from external dll ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, mef, extensible

I'm working on a project where I need to create an extensible ASP.NET MVC Web App which can load 'modules' (views and controllers) from external dll files. I have heard MEF could work but I am stuck on how to implement this. Does anyone know how it can be achieved?